# image Map with Bootstrap Tooltips not showing in correct spot

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an image map and I would like to use the built-in tooltips provided by Bootstrap when a user hovers over a specific part of that image.

The issue I'm having is that the tooltip does not show up in the right place. Right now it shows at the top left corner of the image for all areas of the image map.

How can I move the tooltips under their respective areas without having to reposition each tooltip individually? It should automatically be within the rec defined.

Here is the map code I am using:

```
<img id="Image-Maps-Com-process-map" src="images/osh drawing.png" border="0" width="600" height="600" orgWidth="600" orgHeight="600" usemap="#process-map" alt="" />
<map name="process-map" id="ImageMapsCom-process-map">
<area  alt="" title="Wood Burning Stove" href="#" class="tooltip-bot" data-original-title="Title text here" shape="rect" coords="478,186,572,296" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />
<area  alt="" title="Rough Cut Lumber" href="#" class="tooltip-bot" data-original-title="Title text here" shape="rect" coords="184,1,395,148" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />
<area  alt="This is the description maybe" title="Distributing" href="#"class="tooltip-bot" data-original-title="Title text here" shape="rect" coords="45,398,304,577" style="outline:none;" target="_self"  />
<area  alt="" title="Shipping Materials" href="#"class="tooltip-bot" data-original-title="Title text here" shape="rect" coords="9,52,141,183" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />
<area  alt="" title="Sawdust" href="#"class="tooltip-bot" data-original-title="Title text here" shape="rect" coords="302,311,410,385" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />
<area  alt="" title="Electricity" href="#"class="tooltip-bot" data-original-title="Title text here" shape="rect" coords="430,0,570,113" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />
<area  alt="manufacturing" title="Manufacturing" href="#"class="tooltip-bot" data-original-title="Title text here" shape="poly" coords="348,193,213,197,188,313,221,368,296,362,300,310,357,302,363,193" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />
</map>
```

Comment: It's only Bootstrap, none of their code has been modified for the tooltips

Comment: In firefox and chrome both have different place of tooltip. The tooltip div has same top,left position so it display at same place.

Comment: So your saying I need to manually set the coordinates through CSS so that they display correctly? Or is there a more efficient way of doing it?

Comment: Strangely enough its  better in IE than Chrome or FF. Weird

Comment: I thing you can use Jquery. To get mouse position and display as depend on mouse position.

Comment: @Trisha exactly what i am saying is in DelightedD0D's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm no expert but I feel like this is because the `area` elements have no actual heights or widths. Their boundaries are established using the `coords` attribute which likely is not looked at by bootstrap.

There may be a better way to do this, but a simple fix would be to add the below code to your page.This will position the tooltip a fixed distance from the pointer itself.

### Here is a [working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aoshb9e0/54/)

```
$(document).mousemove( function(e) {    
    var mouseX = e.pageX - $('#Image-Maps-Com-process-map').offset().left - 40;
    var mouseY = e.pageY - $('#Image-Maps-Com-process-map').offset().top + 20;
    $('.tooltip').css({'top':mouseY,'left':mouseX}).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Comment: you were pretty close - the only thing I had to change was the coordinates for the mouseover: `$('.tooltip').css({'top':mouseY-565,'left':mouseX-275}).fadeIn('slow');`

Comment: Now that I look into it more thoroughly, this cannot possibly be responsive enough to work. With the coordinates set to what they are now, it works fine with the window 100% - but if I scale the window smaller and then hover, the tooltip is in a completely different area. How can I fix this?

Comment: I'll update tonight when I get off work, essentially you'll need to add a bit of code to detect to window size and adjust the offsets

Comment: @Trisha What browser are you using? I'm using chrome and I'm not seeing this issue. No matter how much I change the size of the window, the tooltips stay at a consistent distance relative to the area. Does this happen in the jsFiddle, in your own page, or both?

Comment: DelightedDOD - it happens for me in Chrome, IE, and FireFox - and only on the website. I'm thinking something is interfering with it, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: @Trisha try the updated code above. This uses the parent element's offset to keep the distance consistent.

Comment: can you please remove the JSFiddle and link that you created, as it is creating a lot spam traffic to my website. Please reply. Thank You.

Comment: @Trisha I have updated the fiddle with a dummy link. However, I really dont think this is your issue. That link was to a non existant image on your site and was only ever posted here. This question has only been viewed a total of 2207 times in 481 days and not all of those people would have even clicked on the fiddle. What exactly makes you think this dead image link is responsible for your spam traffic?

Answer (score 2):

I know that this is a fairly old and answered question, but I figured I would throw this in as I ran into the same issue and couldn't find an exact answer elsewhere. I have a site that uses an older asp.net chart control that draws image maps over the graphs so that tooltips can be displayed.  To use tooltips on its area attributes and get them in the right places, I used the code below. Note that I still had to use offset amounts, but it worked fairly well.  ".maparea" is a class that is dynamically applied to all of the map area attributes.  I also used mouseover as I did not need the tooltip to move around constantly.

```
$('.maparea').mouseover(function (e) {
    var position = $(this).attr('coords').split(',');
    x = +position[0];
    y = +position[1];
    $('.tooltip').css({ 'top': y + 60, 'left': x - 83 }).fadeIn('slow');
    $('.tooltip-arrow').css({ 'left': '50%' });
});
```

**Edit:**

I had to put in the tooltip-arrow line because Google Chrome was messing up the alignment of the tooltip arrow.  Don't think this will happen in all scenarios but since my page has menus that can be collapsed that will resize the page on their own, they were throwing the alignment off.

Answer (score 1):

My solution for popovers (basing on mouse click position):

```
var clickTop,clickLeft=0;
    $(document).click(function(e){
        clickTop =e.pageY;
        clickLeft =e.pageX;

    });
    $().ready(function(){
        var popovers=$('[data-toggle="popover"]');

        popovers.popover({
            placement: 'bottom center',
            html:true,
            trigger:'focus'
        }).on("shown.bs.popover", function(e){
            $('.popover').css({top:clickTop,left:clickLeft-100});
        })

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I've adopted @Big EMPin solution (right area tooltips), so it works for me at last:

```
<div style="position: relative;display: inline-block">
    <img style="max-width: 100%" src="../static/img/JavaPyramid.jpg" usemap="#courses">
</div>
<map name="courses">
    <area shape="rect" coords="120,10,200,85" href="/view/startjava" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="StartJava" class="maparea">
    <area shape="rect" coords="85,100,165,175" href="/view/basejava" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="BaseJava" class="maparea">
    <area shape="rect" coords="50,190,130,265" href="/view/topjava" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="TopJava" class="maparea">
    <area shape="rect" coords="20,280,100,355" href="/view/masterjava" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="MasterJava" class="maparea">
</map>
<script>
    $('.maparea').mousemove(function (e) {
      var pos = $(this).attr('coords').split(',');
      $('.tooltip').css({'left': parseInt(pos[2]) + 5, 'top': parseInt(pos[1]) + 35}).fadeIn('slow');
    });
</script>
```

Solution can be seen at http://javaops.ru/